# Change Path for OS X

Tags: macos, computing-environment

I am *not* asking how to change the path for mac OS X terminal windows.

I am having [this problem](http://groups.google.com/group/git-cola/browse_thread/thread/ab5f3ec699f2e274), and I’d like to be able to launch by clicking. It does work if I open it in a terminal window (since the path is set correctly).

I have tried adding a path variable to `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` but to no avail.

How can I change the path for the current user in Mac OS X?

Comment: Where is `git` installed?

Comment: Chealion, git is installed in its default location on OSX /usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Um. Generally /usr/local is for stuff that *isn't* default. That is you put "local" installations there... A lot of tarbals configure to go there by default but that is not an OS decision.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the installer for my Git install (which is the most common one) installed there by default. It's true that my OS had git in another location originally, I think, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a file with your desired path in it (e.g. `/opt/local/bin`) to the directory `/etc/paths.d`. This method is [how TeXLive does it](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2009-August/041037.html). You can also add your manpath to `/etc/manpaths.d` this way.

Comment: excellent. I've marked it as "should be on superuser" :)... I'll check it out. +1 for now.

Comment: This worked. I ended up using setenv PATH $PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/ in my /etc/launchd.conf. I did reboot, though perhaps it wasn't necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Ack! Okay, try this. Add your path to `/etc/paths`

Comment: NM. Instead, add a file in `/etc/paths.d` that has your path in it.

Comment: I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Hi Fideli, those paths are not respected by git-cola.... not sure what's up there, but it doesn't read them. The paths in /etc/launchd.conf did better, but destroyed everything in their, um, way. So not sure what to try now.

Comment: Yikes, man. I just tried it right now with git-cola (even checked through some of the Python code). Not a clue what to do about that. Perhaps try building git-cola from source? There seems to be a script available to set up the OS X dev environment for git-cola. It relies on MacPorts: http://github.com/davvid/git-cola/blob/7458da3455620527b5c2bf9ea27877d02b993dfc/darwin/macports-setup-dev-env.sh . Hopefully someone can give you some better advice for this!