# How to change which Python version gets used in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, python

Snow Leopard comes packaged with a version of Python 2.6 that is incompatible with many popular libraries, so I've downloaded a version of Python 2.6 from python.org.  However, when I type `python` at the terminal, I still get the old version of Python.  How can I change this?

`which python` currently gives me `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python`

`ls -l /usr/bin/python` is not a symbolic link to the above (nor to `Versions/Current`).

I have a version at `/opt/local/bin/python2.6` that I wish to be using.

Comment: My Snow Leopard shows `python --version` to be `Python 2.6.1`. What version are you trying to install? I also wonder if somehow changing this would also affect commands like xattr, for which `file /usr/bin/xattr` yields `/usr/bin/xattr: python script text executable`?

Comment: I have a version at "opt/local/bin/python2.6" that I wish to be using.  I am unsure as to how that would affect commands like xattr, though..

Comment: Is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/` listed in your PATH? Like shown by `echo $PATH` (If yes, then changing the PATH might suffice for you.)

Comment: @Arjan, Yeah, it is.  I haven't even modified the path from the default..

Comment: See also [Getting PATH right for python after MacPorts install](http://superuser.com/questions/224744/getting-path-right-for-python-after-macports-install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how this will affect other usage<sup>†</sup> of Python in OS X, but as currently the OS X Python is listed in your `PATH`, you just need to change that:

- For use in Finder, see [Change Path for OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/97498/change-path-for-os-x) (to allow for double-clicking files).
- For use in Terminal, see [Where does $PATH get set in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard)

I don't know if it matters, but just for the archives: on *my* OS X 10.6 (which is an upgrade from 10.4 via 10.5), `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/` is *not* listed in `PATH`. Instead, `which python` yields `/usr/bin/python`.

<sup><sup>†</sup> For example: `file /usr/bin/xattr` yields `/usr/bin/xattr: python script text executable`, and hence might be affected by changing the Python executable!</sup>

Comment: Ah!  So looking at ~/.profile, it seems that Macports added that folder to my path.  I commented that out, and it is pointing to the correct python version now.  Thanks again for all of your help, Arjan.

Comment: @coffee, what do you mean by "the correct python version"? Taking it out of the PATH will make OS X use `/usr/bin/python`, not your new `/opt/local/bin/python2.6`, right?

Comment: nope, it's using the one in /opt/local/bin/... I'm assuming that is listed earlier on the path.