# Getting PATH right for python after MacPorts install

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal, python, path, macports

I can't import some python libraries (PIL, psycopg2) that I just installed with MacPorts. I looked through these forums, and tried to adjust my `PATH` variable in `~/.bash_profile` in order to fix this but it did not work.

I added the location of PIL and psycopg2 to `PATH`.
I know that Terminal is using a version of python in `/usr/local/bin` rather than the one installed by MacPorts at `/opt/local/bin`.

Do I need to use the MacPorts version of Python in order to ensure that PIL and psycopg2 are on sys.path when I use python in Terminal?
Should I switch to the MacPorts version of Python, or will that cause more problems?

In case it is helpful, here are more facts:

PIl and psycopg2 are installed in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages`

`which python`returns`/usr/bin/python`

`$ echo $PATH`returns (I separated each path for easy reading):

```
:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/
:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
:/opt/local/bin
:/opt/local/sbin
:/usr/local/git/bin
:/usr/bin
:/bin
:/usr/sbin
:/sbin
:/usr/local/bin
:/usr/local/git/bin
:/usr/X11/bin
:/opt/local/bin
```

in python, `>>> sys.path` returns:

```
/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/3/Python
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-override
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.7/Python/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/cairo.framework/Versions/1/Python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode
```

I welcome any criticism and comments, if any of the above looks foolish or poorly conceived. I'm new to all of this.
Thanks!

Running OSX 10.6.5 on a MacBook Pro, invoking python 2.6.1 from Terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the 'notes' command after installing python (change python26 to whatever version you installed):

```
$ port notes python26
```

You'll see some variation on post install recommendations:

```
python26 has the following notes:
  To fully complete your installation and make python 2.6 the default,  please
  run:
    sudo port install python_select
    sudo port select python python26
```

You should install `python_select` and then select `python26` as your default Python. Then, if you did indeed install PIL and pyscopg2 using MacPorts (i.e. something like `port install py26-psycopg2 py26-pil`), then you shouldn't have to specify *anything* in `PYTHONPATH`. You also don't need to add the `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/…` directories to your `PATH`. After doing this, `which python` should return `/opt/local/bin/python`. Python ports installed by MacPorts in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` are already in the `sys.path` for MacPorts Python. You were not finding them earlier because you were using the System Python (i.e. `/usr/bin/python`), which has no knowledge of MacPorts Python packages.

Comment: Thank you fideli. Just tried it. It was super easy and totally worked. That is the right way to do it.

Comment: Why does macports require that you select this python? Why is it not selected by itself (atleast on my machine, I installed python for the first time under macports; shouldn't it have automatically selected that?)

Comment: @kalaracey MacPorts attempts to be non-intrusive when there are obvious conflicts, i.e. MacPorts vs System Python. If you would like to use `python26` installed through MacPorts, you must select it using `python-select`. Note that using Python with the full path `/opt/local/bin/python2.6` works as well all the time.

Comment: These days it looks like: `$ port notes python27`
`sudo port select --set python python27`

Answer (score 2):

I *think* I figured out the answer to my question.
I edited my ~/.bash_profile file to include

```
export PYTHONPATH=
```

and then I added all of the existing paths in `sys.path`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/3/Python:/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-override:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.7/Python/site-packages:/Library/Frameworks/cairo.framework/Versions/1/Python:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload:/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages:
```

and then I appended the paths to the directories where MacPorts installed stuff:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages:
```

now when I print sys.path, the paths to the MacPorts install directories are included:

```
/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/3/Python
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-override
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.7/Python/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/cairo.framework/Versions/1/Python
/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/3/Python
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-override
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.7/Python/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/cairo.framework/Versions/1/Python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Now

```
>>> import PIL
```

and

```
>>> import psycopg2
```

work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really resolve the issue of having multiple versions of the same library. If there is a library with the same name in two directories, and both are in PATH, how does one know which will be used?

Comment: Found a book on UNIX and shell programming, which said that when given a command the shell will search through the directories in PATH according to the order that they are listed. In other words the first directory listed when you type echo $PATH will be searched first. I assume the same is true of PYTHONPATH.