# How do I do the Mac equivalent of adding something to the Windows path environment variable?

Tags: macos, command-line, installation, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does $PATH get set in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard)

I need to get a command line program working on my Mac, I have downloaded the executable binaries... not even quite sure where to put them, also need to do whatever the Mac equivalent of adding them to the windows path environment variable is?

The program is blast version 2.2.24 (genetics software)

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the path to the software in your .bash_profile or .bashrc in your home directory.
Open Terminal and do the following:

```
cd ~
vim .bash_profile
PATH=$PATH:path_to_software
export PATH
```

close the file and log out, then log back in and you should be ok.

Comment: typo: `.basrc` should be `.bashrc`

Comment: (digging back through unresolved questions, don't think this one was exactly right, but i think the typo correction fixes it, from memory changing one character made it work)

Comment: ah, works but only in bash