# How to add the current dir to Bash's path and why is it considered a bad idea by some people?

Tags: macos, bash, path

I'd like to add the current dir to the path so i don't have to keep typing stuff like ./a.out over and over.  I also recall someone saying it was a bad idea, but don't remember why. I Windows and DOS it's a common practice…

BTW, I'm using bash and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Where does $PATH get set in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard)

[Why is . not in the path by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default)