# Why I should type "./" when I want running an application that compiled by GCC in Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc

My OS is Fedora Linux 14.

I write a program with Code::Blocks IDE and it compiles my program with GCC.

My output program is `test`. When I start my application in Code::Blocks it starts normally. But when I double click on my executable program, the program does not starts. When I start a terminal (in path of my binary program), and type `test`, my program does not starts, but whrn I type `./test` in terminal, it starts normaly. Why I should type `./` when I want running an application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add the current dir to Bash's path and why is it considered a bad idea by some people?](http://superuser.com/questions/196902/how-to-add-the-current-dir-to-bashs-path-and-why-is-it-considered-a-bad-idea-by)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`./` is necessary when your `PATH` environment variable does not include the current directory.  So if you have an executable in some directory that is not on your path, you need `./theexecutable` to tell the shell that your executable is in the current directory.

Comment: Even if `.` is in the path if `/bin/` is before `.` in the `PATH` it will not execute `test`. `/bin/test` exists (see the man page). Avoid calling your test program "test" to avoid confusion.

Comment: There are also good reasons to not put `.` in your PATH.

Answer (score 4):

Simply because the current directory `.`, is normally not included in the PATH variable.

If you don't what to type `./`, you could add `.` to the colon separated list of folders contained in PATH, however is not recommended, because it would be easy to mask system commands without realising it.

Comment: Rather than adding ".", I would instead add the specific directory your programs are compiled in, e.g. ~amir/codeblocks/executables. (I have no idea if that's the right directory but I hope I have gotten the idea across.)

Comment: It's somewhat okay to add `.` **at the end** of $PATH. Still not recommended, though.

Comment: @grawity At the end will not work in this case `/bin/test/` exists and will be executed instead of `./test` since `/bin/` will be before the current did. I would not call my test program test (a common unix utility)

Answer (score 2):

When you just type the program name, *nix will look through all your PATH locations for that name. If it doesn't find it, it won't start. So you must enter "./" to indicate the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other answers tell you:

When you type `test`, you're probably invoking `/bin/test`; `man test` for details.

When you double-click on the executable (from nautilus or something similar, yes?), it probably does run, but without a terminal you can't see the output.