# 'brew doctor' command not recognizing path changes

Tags: macos, path, homebrew

When I run brew doctor, I get /user/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin  So I changed my /etc/paths and my ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist as this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard) said to do.  When I run brew doctor again, I still get the same error.  Any tips?  Thanks

Comment: I started a new shell and it worked.  Not sure why I had to so it would still be nice if someone could shed some light on that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change environment files, you have to tell the shell to manually read them to update the environment.  Closing the terminal and reopening is one way to do it, but a more efficient way is to use the `source` command.

Also, I would avoid editing any files that require sudo access, such as `/etc/paths`.  A safer way to edit your path would be to add the line

```
export PATH=/new/path/name/:$PATH
```

to the file `~/.profile` (it may not exist on your computer) then run

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

to have your changes take effect.  By editing your `~/.profile` instead of a system file such as `/etc/paths` you are safeguarding against user error.  If you need to reset to the default `PATH` settings at some point in the future, simply delete that line from `~/.profile`.  However, you will have to manually change `/etc/paths` again to revert to default.  `~/.profile` will automatically be `source`d by Terminal.app when a new shell is opened if it exists, so you only need to do this once.

Comment: In the post i linked, the first comment recommends to change the /etc/paths file, that's why i did it.  Is his recommendation incorrect?

Comment: To say it's incorrect would be incorrect.  I'd say it depends on your philosophy of maintaining your system.  Personally, I like to keep all modifications (such as changing my PATH) in single file (i.e. ~/.profile) so that if I need, I can "instantly" return to the system default.  There also may be cases when a program assumes that the system path in /etc/paths is default and may break if it is not (this is not likely, but it could happen).  If you don't have an issue with messing with your system files, then I can't tell you that it is incorrect.  It's just that I wouldn't do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change environment settings, you have to start a new shell to pick up those changes. This is by design, to ensure that changes you make won't impact existing shell sessions.

You will see this behaviour in most OSes.