# uglifyjs: command not found

Tags: macos, command-line, node.js

I'm trying to use uglifyjs via command line, and it's not going well.

I've tried many variations of `$ [sudo] npm install uglify-js -g`, but in all cases, when I try to run uglifyjs as a command `$ uglifyjs` it says command not found.

In every case, it seems like uglify gets installed. Version 2.4.0 is listed under `$ npm list -g` as being installed.

I'm running: 
node v0.10.17 (installed via pkg from node homepage )
npm v1.3.8

I've restarted a couple of times after various installations, but I'm not getting any success.

```
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/uglifyjs -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
uglify-js@2.4.0 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/uglify-js
├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.1
├── async@0.2.9
├── source-map@0.1.29 (amdefine@0.0.8)
└── optimist@0.3.7 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:node_modules andrewheins$ uglifyjs
-bash: uglifyjs: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems that /usr/local/share/npm/bin/uglifyjs is where the program was installed and /usr/local/share/npm/bin/ is not in your PATH environment variable. What happens if you issue as a command /usr/local/share/npm/bin/uglifyjs ? I am not familiar with this software or your set-up, this is just reasoning from general principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @micans comment above, and [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard), I was able to get uglify working by adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin/` to my .bash_profile. Thanks all!

Answer (score 23):

My problem was that I installed `uglifyjs`, and not `uglify-js`. `uglifyjs` does not include the binary. Just leaving this here if someone else is stuck the same way.

`sudo npm install -g uglify-js`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my Linux Mint installation.
I resolved it just executing the follows commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```